# Rotating an image around a point of axis depending on browser width/height

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to put some code together that will take an image that is pointing to another part of the site and adjust it based on the users current browser width/height so that it is always facing where it too.

Kind of like those pictures with eyes that follow you round the room, only this time the painting is pointing and that goes up and down depending on its position.

I assume this is a job for canvas but if anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated!

Comment: Question is a bit confusing. Do you want an image to rotate towards mouse position inside the window?

Comment: Do you have an example or some code we can see?

Comment: No, I want the image to always be facing a point on my page. Depending on the size of the browser, it should readjust itself.